# Python can't find module "site"

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to run a game which seems to need Python2.2. When I start the game nothing happens, so I brought back my *very* basic debugging skills and found out that the code calls a function called "*InitializeEx*" with "*site*" as parameter, then fails with "*ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (00000002)*" and exits. I googled and it seems like site is a module of Python.

The problem is I have never had any contact with Python and all this modules-stuff. I think I even have multiple versions of Python installed on my PC (just downloaded 2.2). Can I somehow just download this library and install it?

I'm using Windows 10 Proffesional x64.

*PS: I wasn't really sure if I should post this to StackOverflow or SuperUser. So if you are a moderator feel free to move this to the right place :)*

Comment: "File not found" means it looked for a file and didn't find it, because you don't have it in the right place and with the right name.

Comment: I know, my quesiton is how I can install it and where I have to install it.

Comment: If it was trying to import a module and couldn't find it, you would probably (not sure with Python 2.2) get an `ImportError` instead.

Comment: I'm running it in OllyDBG debugger, I can only see assembly code, so maybe the error messages there are different?

Comment: 1)Are you sure it's specifically 2.2? It's a very ancient version, released in 2002-2003. 2)W/o any specific info like a [mcve] we cannot say anything but guess around 3)FYI, [OllyDbg can use symbols and sources](https://forum.tuts4you.com/topic/19394-ollydbg-load-source-code/) (though there aren't PDBs for the public version of 2.2. [They appear to have started publishing them since 2.7.1](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/Symbols-for-Python-mixed-mode-debugging)).